# NGINX module exit thread / master callbacks

Tags: module, nginx, httpserver

I'm experiencing some troubles (and headaches) with my little nginx module.
I've seen a lot of module code lately, and a ton of stuff about nginx modules but I can't manage to do what I need to.
Here is my problem:
I have created my own nginx module called "mymodule". Its loc_conf structure looks like that:

```
typedef struct {
    void *serverConf;
    ngx_str_t server_file;
} ngx_http_mymodule_loc_conf_t;
```

its command structure looks like that:

```
static ngx_command_t ngx_http_mymodule_commands[] = {
  {
   ngx_string("mymodule"),
   NGX_HTTP_LOC_CONF | NGX_CONF_TAKE1,
   ngx_http_mymodule,
   NGX_HTTP_LOC_CONF_OFFSET,
   0,
   NULL
  },
ngx_null_command 
};
```

in the ngx_http_mymodule function I do some stuff and set the serverConf pointer in the ngx_http_mymodule_loc_conf_t.
The problem is that I would like to retrieve that serverConf pointer when the thread / process is exited. But the only parameter given to ngx_module_t while exiting thread process or master is a ngx_cycle_t* and I can't find how to retrieve the ngx_http_mymodule_loc_conf_t from it in order to work on that serverConf pointer.

[EDIT]
I have tried this in the thread exit callback with no luck at having a not null serverConf pointer:

```
ngx_http_mymodule_loc_conf_t *mymodulecf = (ngx_http_mymodule_loc_conf_t *)ngx_get_conf(cycle->conf_ctx, ngx_http_mymodule_module);
```

Any help or idea would be appreciated :) Thanks in advance.